# regex search for text-block after series of words

Tags: regex

I'm not a regex expert, far from, most of my regex are copy-paste with a slight altering from questions/answers found here.
We are searching in router logs for text, I received samples from 40 routers and created a regex that worked.

```
regex_to_find = "(?s)(?<=VPN  IF NAME    ID     VIRTUAL IP  VIRTUAL MAC        PRIORITY  PRIORITY  STATE    STATE  TIMER          TIMER    LAST STATE CHANGE TIME     LIST    STATE)(.*?)(?=" + routername + ")"
    regex_result = re.search(regex_to_find, filecontent)
```

But now I received the files from all 650 routers and it seems that the start of the columns depends on the width of the fields in the list below. So as an example it could be that these 2 headers can be found in different files.

```
VPN   IF_NAME .....
VPN     IF_NAME .....
```

So I need the create a regex that would search like this (expression in spoken language)..

Find the block of text between a line that starts with

"VPN" followed somewhere by "IF_NAME" followed by ... and finally "STATE"

and the block ends with #PMZ0350 (which is the routername)

This is a sample of such a log, there are multiple kinds of data in such a file, for each block-type we have a separate code block.

```
PZMO120#
PZMO120# show interface description

                                              IF      IF      IF                                                                                    IPV6
                      AF                      ADMIN   OPER    TRACKER                                                                               ADMIN
VPN    INTERFACE      TYPE  IP ADDRESS        STATUS  STATUS  STATUS   DESC                                                                         STATUS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0      ge0/0          ipv4  xx.yy.zz.r/pp     Up      Up      Up       ORCH=NETWORK - To INTERNET                                                   Up
0      ge0/1          ipv4  -                 Up      Up      NA       ORCH=NETWORK - TLOC Extension - B2B between Primary vEdge & Secondary vEdge  Up
0      ge0/2          ipv4  -                 Down    Down    NA       None                                                                         Up
65530  ge0/3          ipv4  -                 Up      Up      NA       ORCH=NETWORK - CUSTOMER LAN - Service VPN physical interface                 Up

PZMO120#
PZMO120#
PZMO120# show  vrrp

                                                                                                          PRIMARY                             TRACK   PREFIX
                GROUP                                            REAL      VRRP     OMP    ADVERTISEMENT  DOWN                                PREFIX  LIST
VPN  IF NAME    ID     VIRTUAL IP   VIRTUAL MAC        PRIORITY  PRIORITY  STATE    STATE  TIMER          TIMER    LAST STATE CHANGE TIME     LIST    STATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    ge0/3.510  10     zz.zz.zz.x   00:00:??:00:01:0a  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -
2    ge0/3.511  11     yy.yy.yy.r   00:00:??:00:01:0b  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -

PZMO120#
PZMO120# show  run vpn 1
```

Comment: I just tried this in Autoit. $log = ClipGet()
;~ ConsoleWrite($log & @CRLF)
$results = StringRegExp($log, '(?m)(?s)(?i)(VPN\s*IF\s*NAME.*?)#', 3)

For $i = 0 To UBound($results) -1
 ConsoleWrite('!' & $results[$i] & @CRLF)
Next

Comment: I was able to use part of if, but I the \s between VPN and IF can be sometimes more than 1 space, if've tried [\s]{2,} but that fails ...

Comment: \s* should do want you need. The * got lost by the copy process. Do not know why. Just use \s* everywhere.

Comment: You can try `regex_to_find = r"^VPN[^\S\n]+IF[^\S\n]+NAME\b.*\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\r?\n" +  routername`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify a bit the "*VPN ... STATE*" line pattern, also get rid of the line of hyphens and as you are using *Python* I would create a group so that you don't need to use a positive lookbehind which will be more constraining.

The regex would become:

```
^VPN\s+IF NAME\b.+\bSTATE\s*-+\s*(.*?)\s+PZMO120#
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/tpZEkU/3

With the use of the `m` flag for **m**ultiline so that we can use the `^` in front of "*VPN*", the `s` flag so that the `.` matches also new lines.

- We'll use `\s*` to match spaces, tabs and new lines.
- The `\b` after "*NAME*" or before "*STATE*" is to match a word **b**oundary.
- `-+` is to match the "-------" line below the column titles.
- Then our interesting part is the capturing group `(.*?)` which is ungreedy
  so that it doesn't go too far in case you have multiple times a log entry
  to extract from the log file.
- We finish with some spaces, tabs or new lines followed by the router name
  and the final hashtag.

In the *Python* code, don't forget to escape the router name as it may contain
some chars that have a meaning in the regex pattern syntax.

```py
import re

routername = "PZMO120"
regex = r"^VPN\s+IF NAME\b.+\bSTATE\s*-+\s*(.*?)\s+" + re.escape(routername) + "#"

log = ("PZMO120#\n"
    "PZMO120# show interface description\n\n"
    "                                              IF      IF      IF                                                                                    IPV6\n"
    "                      AF                      ADMIN   OPER    TRACKER                                                                               ADMIN\n"
    "VPN    INTERFACE      TYPE  IP ADDRESS        STATUS  STATUS  STATUS   DESC                                                                         STATUS\n"
    "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
    "0      ge0/0          ipv4  xx.yy.zz.r/pp     Up      Up      Up       ORCH=NETWORK - To INTERNET                                                   Up\n"
    "0      ge0/1          ipv4  -                 Up      Up      NA       ORCH=NETWORK - TLOC Extension - B2B between Primary vEdge & Secondary vEdge  Up\n"
    "0      ge0/2          ipv4  -                 Down    Down    NA       None                                                                         Up\n"
    "65530  ge0/3          ipv4  -                 Up      Up      NA       ORCH=NETWORK - CUSTOMER LAN - Service VPN physical interface                 Up\n\n"
    "PZMO120#\n"
    "PZMO120#\n"
    "PZMO120# show  vrrp\n\n"
    "                                                                                                          PRIMARY                             TRACK   PREFIX\n"
    "                GROUP                                            REAL      VRRP     OMP    ADVERTISEMENT  DOWN                                PREFIX  LIST\n"
    "VPN  IF NAME    ID     VIRTUAL IP   VIRTUAL MAC        PRIORITY  PRIORITY  STATE    STATE  TIMER          TIMER    LAST STATE CHANGE TIME     LIST    STATE\n"
    "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
    "1    ge0/3.510  10     zz.zz.zz.x   00:00:??:00:01:0a  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -\n"
    "2    ge0/3.511  11     yy.yy.yy.r   00:00:??:00:01:0b  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -\n\n"
    "PZMO120#\n"
    "PZMO120# show  run vpn 1")

matches = re.findall(regex, log, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
```

You'll just have to loop over your matches and see what it captured in the group.

The output in our case is an array with one match containing the 2 lines of interesting data:

```
['1    ge0/3.510  10     zz.zz.zz.x   00:00:??:00:01:0a  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -\n2    ge0/3.511  11     yy.yy.yy.r   00:00:??:00:01:0b  150       150       primary  up     1              3        2022-12-06T19:32:06+00:00  -       -']
```

You could then easily split the lines on `\r?\n` and extract what you need from them.